# Pass command-line argument to schemacrawler programmatically

Tags: java, schemacrawler

I'm using SchemaCrawler v14.21.02 programmatically in my Java project to generate schema diagrams. I would like to generate a diagram with a reduced set of columns, as done by adding the option `-infolevel=standard -command=brief` when running SchemaCrawler from the command line.

My question is: how do I pass this option when running SchemaCrawler programmatically?

I have found the `SchemaInfoLevel` and `SchemaInfoLevelBuilder` classes in package `schemacrawler.schemacrawler`, but the `-command=brief` option eludes me.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the example code provided as part of the SchemaCrawler project, at [ExecutableExample.java](https://github.com/schemacrawler/SchemaCrawler/blob/acb9bfe7735918d6228fbff1f93f9b88b077fd14/schemacrawler-examplecode/src/main/java/ExecutableExample.java#L49-L52). I have highlighted the relevant parts of the code, if you click on the link.

Sualeh Fatehi, [SchemaCrawler](https://www.schemacrawler.com/)